# jquery load a selector contained in a variable

Tags: jquery, variables, load, selector

Can anyone help me with the right syntax to load some div, please

I try'd to concat it in several ways, except the right way

```
rcp= "#div02";
$("#content").load("/inc/forms.php " +rcp'"', function(){....
```

*I will keep trying in the meantime*

**EDIT**

AND ACCIDENTLY GOT IT RIGHT (not completely yet)

$("#content").load("/inc/forms.php #" +rcp, function(){.... is ok

BUT before the load function the ajax function is called, and returns with the rcp variable
I think now it is a variable scope problem.
I already try'd setting a global rpc variable, but it's not working, not yet anyway!

```
var avp ='';

$("a.order").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
url: "/order/request",
cache: false,
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
timeout: 5000,
success: function(data)
{
if(data.check){         //ingelogd??


    avp = data.requestpage.avp;
}

}//EINDE success

});//EINDE ajax


$("#content").load("/inc/forms.php #"+avp, function()                                                       
});//EINDE LOAD

});
```

thanks in adv, Richard

Comment: I make the assumption that you have an element with an ID attribute of "content".  Take out the '"', that seems odd in there.

Comment: I must have lag, running behind your posts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have an extra " character appending there for some reason which isn't needed and is probably making it try to find the selector actually called div02"

```
rcp= "div02";
$("#content").load("/inc/forms.php #" +rcp+'"', function(){....
```

Change that to

```
    rcp= "div02";
$("#content").load("/inc/forms.php #" +rcp, function(){....
```

Edit:

Your $.ajax() function is returning AFTER your load function - put your load function into the success function of $.ajax

Comment: LOL it happens to all of us, like trying to back out of a room in a FPS game after the 6 players in there shot you already :)

Comment: uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: # is what I get??

Comment: @Mark, just caught this error, when I try to load it in firebug

Comment: As a test, change the +rpc to #div02 in the string, - suspect the function is not returning a data object myself: load( url, [data], [callback] )

Comment: I have a similar sample working here so doesn't seem to be a variable scope thing?

Sample code:

$(document).ready(function(){
 var test = 'div02';
    $("#something").load("/testbed/test.html #"+test, function(){alert('test');});
  });

Comment: jaminute, I will give the complete function

Comment: Your $.ajax() function is returning AFTER your load function - put your load function into the success function of $.ajax

Comment: yes, I noticed too, I put an alert between those too, and that one returned first. I should be alright now. Everything ok, thanks @Ben,@Mark